# How to hide plugin options for editors via functions.php

Tags: plugins, admin, permissions, capabilities, user-roles

I've read the entry ***Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file***, it really help me a lot.

I only got a question, **is there a way to hide some plugins options (in their respective administrations), just like the way you hide the widgets at the dashboard?**. This because I have to let the editor manage some parts of the plugin, but not all (for example, in a slider, he/she must edit the images to display, but not the dimensions of the slider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easiest way, just add the line to wp-config.php, this will disable plugin and theme editor, both. 
    `define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT',true);`

If you want to add codes into theme's function, the code should work for you.

```
function ra_block_tp_edit( $caps, $cap ) {
    if($cap == 'edit_plugins' )
        $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
    return $caps;
}
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'ra_block_tp_edit', 10, 3 );
```

Best of luck.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, mark my answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few options, but, depending on the situation, code isn't the easiest way that I know to deal with this particular circumstance.

First, if your plug-in has a particular capability that is required for accessing those options, you can ensure that your users do not have that capability and write a check in your functions.php to see if user->has_cap(). It really depends on what plug-in you are using and how it's set up as to the best way to incorporate this.

Another option, if it has capabilities would be to use something like the [Role Scoper Plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) or the [Members Plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) to remove that capability through a User Interface instead of code.

Another option, if your plug-in doesn't have specific capabilities would be to set the user level to something like Editor and then use the [Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) Plug-in to remove the settings from that user-level's admin menu.

Personally, I'd recommend the Admin Menu Editor, I use it on most of our projects to limit the user's access to various things that I don't want them to accidentally break.

I know it wasn't exactly the answer you were looking for, but if you provide some more info on that plug-in, specifically a name and a link, perhaps I can check into the best way to hook into it.

Hope this helped a little.